# Ruby how to write a consecutive division

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How to write a method to achieve this function efficiently?

```
divide_array([a,b,c]) # return a.to_f / b.to_f / c.to_f
divide_array([a,b,c,d,e]) # return a.to_f / b.to_f / c.to_f / d.to_f / d.to_f
```

Here is what I can image

```
def divide_array(array)
  return false if array.include?(0)
  result = 0
  array.each_with_index do |i, index|
    break if index >= array.size - 1
    result = i.to_f / array[index + 1].to_f
  end

  result
end
```

But I thought Ruby is an elegant language, it must be a better and efficient way to achieve that. (Maybe like `reduce` or `inject`?)

Comment: Your question would be clearer if your examples contained actual numbers, such as `divide_array([52,2,4,2)) #=> ((52/2)/4)/2 => ((26.0)/4)/2 => 6.5/2 => 3.25`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I deleted my comment. I was actually referencing that style guide and completely got the `reduce` over `inject` backwards. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

inject (or reduce) indeed, but `to_f` and division can be done in one go by `fdiv`:

```
[3,2,1].inject(:fdiv)  #=> 1.5
```

More precise is converting to Rationals, and only convert to Float as late as possible. Demo:

```
[3,5,6].map(&:to_f).inject(:/)    # => 0.09999999999999999
[3,5,6].map(&:to_r).inject(:/).to_f # =>  0.1
```

As sagarpandya82 comments (and new for me), this conversion to Rational and division can also be done in one go, culminating in:

```
[3,5,6].inject(:quo).to_f #=> 0.1
```

Comment: Another method (`fdiv`) for my tool kit. Good to know.

Comment: Do you mean `to_f` in your first sentence?

Comment: I think this `[3,5,6].inject(:quo).to_f #=> 0.1` is a nice amalgamation of your answers. Feel free to add to your answer.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 Nice, and new to me. Added.

Comment: Yet another possibility: `arr = [52,2,4,2]; arr.reduce((arr.first.**2).to_f, :/) #=> 3.25`.Note :/) is not an emoticon.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a elegant way to do it:

```
[3,2,1].map(&:to_f).reduce(:/)
# => 1.5
```

The same thing written without proc shorthands:

```
[3,2,1].reduce { |quotient, el| quotient.to_f / el.to_f }
```

Comment: Best to allow readers decide what is "elegant". For one, there is the possibility that someone else (as here) will post an answer that is even more elegant. :-). It still deserves my upvote.

Comment: I believe the second answer is better because it skips iterating over the list which is an O(n) operation. While both solutions are O(n), there is actual optimization to be had in the second solution which could be important in a real scenario with huge arrays.